Ansible check output of command and return the incorrected value if a string matched with condition
I write a playbook to check command docker ps --all output then check if there is a names ansiblecontrol in output of line then get the value of images.
Here down is my playbook:
---
- name: Check and update Docker toolkit status
  hosts: dockerhost0
  become: yes
  become_method: su

  tasks:
    - name: Check list of docker containers in host
      command: docker ps --all
      register: docker_ps_output

    - name: Debug Docker output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ docker_ps_output.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: Set fact based on command output
      set_fact:
        toolstatus: >-
          {% set found = 'unavailable' %}
          {% for line in docker_ps_output.stdout_lines %}
            {% if 'ansiblecontroll' in line %}
              {% set parts = line.split() %}
              {% set found = parts[1] %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {{ found }}

    - name: Debug toolstatus
      debug:
        msg: "Toolstatus is set to: {{ toolstatus }}"

Here is the output:
TASK [Check list of docker containers in host] **************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [dockerhost0]

TASK [Debug Docker output] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dockerhost0] => {
    "msg": [
        "CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                       COMMAND    CREATED       STATUS           PORTS  NAMES", 
        "468bc9a43749  localhost/toolac.di.1.0.0.2024.28.2:latest  /bin/bash  3 weeks ago   Up 3 weeks ago          ansiblecontrol", 
        "ad73b324913e  localhost/toolac.di.1.0.0.2024.12.4:latest  /bin/bash  3 months ago  Up 3 months ago         acnode"
    ]
}

TASK [Set fact based on command output] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dockerhost0]

TASK [Debug toolstatus] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dockerhost0] => {
    "msg": "Toolstatus is set to:                   unavailable"
}

The return value is incorrect as expected although there is string ansiblecontrol appeared in output. The return value should be localhost/toolac.di.1.0.0.2024.28.2:latest in stead of unavailable.
What's wrong in my condition processing codes?

It seems you are going to (re-)implement functionality which is already there out-of-box, Custom facts.

I gonna go crazy with this condition processing, is there anything need to change  on the logic of condition to let ansible process correctly?

There are many solutions possible, one is within the docker itself already, like docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'. docker ps output formatting: list only .... Others would be in the shell command. In any case it is recommended to pre-process instead of post-process within Ansible.

See also How to execute a Bash command only if a Docker container with a given name does not exist? as it is currently looks like a XY problem?.

The purpose is to find the Image's name with Names "ansiblecontrol", then set it as a fact and I will will use that fact to update it to a another variable file to use it in other tasks. But my playbook cannot set_fact correctly.

It is definitely a feasible Use Case. But what I've indicated is that you should only gather the image name if it is there and do not do any processing within or with Ansible. Just gather the fact. Do it with the docker command only, or even with some processing in shell.

Use the proposed module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-container-info-module

You have a typo in your code. You spelled control with two letter l.

If your goal is "find the image used for the anisblecontrol container, if it exists", then the simplest solution is going to be something like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: get information about ansiblecontrol container
    community.docker.docker_container_info:
      name: ansiblecontrol
    register: container

  - when: container.container is none
    fail:
      msg: No ansiblecontrol container exists

  - debug:
      var: container.container.Config.Image

This relies on the community.docker collection.
It will either successfully retrieve information about the anisblecontrol container, in which case you can get the name of the image as shown, or the value of container.container will be none.

thanks @larsks, that is exactly what i need

Glad to help! If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.
